# Flutter - Add lib Flutter to Project Android

Tags: android, flutter

I'm developing a project Android (size about 600Mb) on IDE Android Studio. 
Now, I want to add Library Flutter to my Project. But I did not find any way. 
Please help me with this problem.

Comment: What is "Library Flutter"? What does "add to my project" mean? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://flutter.io/get-started/install/)? This is not a gradle library that you can normally import into your project. You've to create a flutter project separately and work in that.

Comment: follow the instructions in the documentation that i linked

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to add flutter to an existing project, you can  just embed a `FlutterView` into an existing android or ios project. For switching between fullscreen android and flutter views, you can look into [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/platform_view) example.

To have a part of your view using flutter, you can take a look at flutter view example [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_view).

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

At the root of your project, look for the pubspec.yaml file.

- android
- ios
- lib
- test pubspec.yaml

in the part of dependencies, you will add the libraries that you want

```
dependencies:
   google_maps_flutter: ^ 0.0.3 + 3
   url_launcher: ^ 4.0.3
   flutter:
     sdk: flutter

   # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
   # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
   cupertino_icons: ^ 0.1.2
   http: any
```

Remember that the indentation is very important in this file